# Python turtle tic tac toe

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, tic-tac-toe, python-turtle

I'm new to python and I programed a tic tac toe with an AI that plays against you. Everything is working but I used textboxes to inform the AI what the player chose. Now I want to upgrade my game so that the player can click on the box he wants to fill instead of typing it in the textbox. My idea was to use `onscreenclick()` but I'm having some issues. `onscreenclick()` returns the coordinates that have been clicked on the canvas and I want to use a function to determine in which box the player clicked.

I got this:

```
from turtle import * 

def whichbox(x,y): #obviously i got 9 boxes but this is just an example for box 1
    if x<-40 and x>-120:
        if y>40 and y<120:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        return 0

box=onscreenclick(whichbox)
print(box)
```

It's obvious that I want box to be 0 or 1 in this case but instead the value of box is `None`. Does anyone know how to fix this? It has to do something with the variable `box` because I if replace `return 1` with `print("1")` it works. I assume that the variable gets defined to quickly.

The second question that I have is if its possible pause the programm until the player clicked on a box but its more important to look at the first problem first.

Comment: `whichbox` cannot return `None`. Besides, negative x coordinate is suspicious. Can't you print x and y when whichbox is called?

Comment: you need to get the x,y coordinates and send them to whichbox.

Comment: yes i can print the x and y but thats not what I'm aiming for. Sry if this question is dumb or obvious but as i said I'm not very good in programing so how can i put x and y in a variable without finishing the program?

Comment: This isn't a package I use, but I'm saying that you're not sending anything to whichbox. If the results from onscreenclick are (x,y), you would need to do: box = whichbox(onscreenclick[0], onscreenclick[1]) or change what the function is expecting. The way this is currently written, you're sending the variable whichbox (which isn't a variable) to the function onscreenclick

Comment: `onscreenclick()` simply remembers the specified function, for later use whenever a click occurs.  It does not, and fundamentally CANNOT, return anything about a particular click, because no click has occurred yet.  Anything you want to do in response to a click should be entirely contained in your `whichbox()` function - returning anything from it is pointless.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what `onscreenclick(()` does.  But it doesn't matter as the is the wrong way to go about this problem.  Instead, use a grid of nine square turtles and their individual `onclick()` handlers to avoid the decoding math.  [Here's a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49785949/5771269)  I swear I provided a similar comment to a similar question by the same OP yesterday but all that's disappeared.  Deja vu.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have named your Screen() in the turtle module, you should then put

```
screen.onscreenclick(whichbox)
```

instead of:

```
onscreenclick(whichbox)
```

Example:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
turtle = Turtle()
screen = Screen()

def ExampleFunction():
    return 7

screen.onscreenclick(ExampleFunction)
```

Furthermore, jasonharper is correct when he says the onscreenclick() function is unable to return any value. As such, you can include a print function within your function whichbox() in order to print out a value, like:

```
def whichbox(x,y): 
    if x<-40 and x>-120:
        if y>40 and y<120:
            print(1)
            return 1
        else:
            print(0)
            return 0
    else:
        print(0)
        return 0
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to keep the print statement outside of whichbox(), you could also do the following:

```
screen.onscreenclick(lambda x, y: print(whichbox(x, y)))
```

which creates a lambda function that gives (x, y) from onscreenclick() to a print statement containing whichbox().

Answer (score 2):

Here's a stripped down example from [the code I linked to in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49785949/5771269).  If you click on a square, it will print to the console window its number, from 0 to 8:

```
from turtle import Turtle, mainloop

CURSOR_SIZE = 20
SQUARE_SIZE = 60

def drawBoard():
    for j in range(3):
        for i in range(3):
            square = Turtle('square', visible=False)
            square.shapesize(SQUARE_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
            square.fillcolor('white')
            square.penup()
            square.goto((i - 1) * (SQUARE_SIZE + 2), (j - 1) * (SQUARE_SIZE + 2))

            number = j * 3 + i
            square.onclick(lambda x, y, number=number: whichsquare(number))
            square.showturtle()

def whichsquare(number):
    print(number)

drawBoard()

mainloop()
```

There is no position decoding involved -- we let turtle handle that for us.